# Please explain Linux bash exec and ssh-agent behavior

Tags: linux, bash, shell, exec, ssh-agent

According to https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Deployment_Guide/s3-openssh-config-ssh-agent.html

I need to execute `exec /usr/bin/ssh-agent $SHELL` and as I understand it `exec` replaces my current shell with the program I specify.

I read http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/ssh-agent.1?query=ssh-agent&sec=1 which states "If a commandline is given, this is executed as a sub process of the agent. When the command dies, so does the agent."

So I guess what I expect that is bash is replaced by ssh-agent, but because I specified a commandline, a new bash is executed, then the ssh-agent is executed, and the old bash is replaced.

What is really happening?

Answer (score 3):

Not quite. What happens is exactly what the documentation says will happen.

1. `exec` replaces the currently running shell with `ssh-agent`, so the "old bash" has now been replaced.
2. `ssh-agent` sees that it has a non-option argument (the value of `$SHELL`), so it creates a child process and in the child process `exec`s that command. That causes `ssh-agent`'s child to be replaced with a new `bash`.
3. `ssh-agent` itself now waits for its child to finish.
4. Meanwhile, the new `bash` has inherited the terminal so it starts responding to your commands.
5. Eventually, you get tired of doing whatever you were doing, and you either `exit` or type a control-D (end-of-file), at which the `bash` process terminates.
6. `ssh-agent` notices that its child finished, so it, too, exits.
7. If the original `bash` process had a parent, that parent now gets notified that its child has terminated. If the original `bash`'s parent no longer exists, the `init` process (process 1) has become the parent. In either case, the parent -- assuming that it is well-behaved -- does something appropriate and cleans up the child's status code in order to avoid leaving a zombie.

Note that "replaced" means that the executable running in the process has been replaced. It doesn't mean that the process itself has been terminated and a new process started. After calling `exec`, a process is still the same process, with the same process-id and the same parent (and, for that matter, the same controlling terminal and the same open file descriptors, except for the file descriptors which the process had marked to be "closed on exec"). If the preceding sentence appears too complicated, the minimum take-away is "the same parent".